# sympy+matplotlib not plotting geometric primitives

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, sympy

I'm trying to plot some geometric primitives in ipython (lines, circles, ellipses), following the [sympy documentation](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/plotting.html).

I am using Sympy release 1.1.1 and python 3.5, on the [CoCalc](https://cocalc.org) system, but can reproduce identical results on my own local installation of ipython and sympy (2.7 and 0.7.6).  Here is my code:

```
from sympy import Point, Circle
from sympy.plotting.plot import Plot
p = Plot(axes='label_axes=True')
c = Circle(Point(0,0), 1)
p[0] = c
```

Now, when I enter `p` on an input line, ipython just returns the object but doesn't plot it:

```
In[2] = p
Out[2] = <sympy.plotting.plot.Plot at 0x7f2e64fe62e8>
```

The plot command works as expected, so the `matplotlib` backend is functional.

When I enter `p.show()`, I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-15-02f33f5f7a8f> in <module>()
----> 1 p.show()

/ext/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py in show(self)
    194             self._backend.close()
    195         self._backend = self.backend(self)
--> 196         self._backend.show()
    197 
    198     def save(self, path):
/ext/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py in show(self)
   1027 
   1028     def show(self):
-> 1029         self.process_series()
   1030         #TODO after fixing https://github.com/ipython/ipython/issues/1255
   1031         # you can uncomment the next line and remove the pyplot.show() call
/ext/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py in process_series(self)
    989                 starts = [s.start for s in parent._series]
    990                 ends = [s.end for s in parent._series]
--> 991                 self.ax.set_xlim(min(starts), max(ends))
    992         if parent.ylim:
    993             self.ax.set_ylim(parent.ylim)
ValueError: min() arg is an empty sequence
```

It displays and empty set of coordinate axes (without the circle).  Also, `p.save("foo.png")` produces a similar error.

I have also tried `p = Plot(Circle((0,0),1)` (although this is not what the documentation suggests to do), and again nothing is shown, with `p.show()` producing another long error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-f1f858abbdb7> in <module>()
      1 p = Plot(Circle((0,0),1))
----> 2 p.show()

/ext/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py in show(self)
    193         if hasattr(self, '_backend'):
    194             self._backend.close()
--> 195         self._backend = self.backend(self)
    196         self._backend.show()
    197 
/ext/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py in __new__(cls, parent)
   1065         matplotlib = import_module('matplotlib', min_module_version='1.1.0', catch=(RuntimeError,))
   1066         if matplotlib:
-> 1067             return MatplotlibBackend(parent)
   1068         else:
   1069             return TextBackend(parent)
/ext/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py in __init__(self, parent)
    872     def __init__(self, parent):
    873         super(MatplotlibBackend, self).__init__(parent)
--> 874         are_3D = [s.is_3D for s in self.parent._series]
    875         self.matplotlib = import_module('matplotlib',
    876             __import__kwargs={'fromlist': ['pyplot', 'cm', 'collections']},
/ext/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/sympy/plotting/plot.py in <listcomp>(.0)
    872     def __init__(self, parent):
    873         super(MatplotlibBackend, self).__init__(parent)
--> 874         are_3D = [s.is_3D for s in self.parent._series]
    875         self.matplotlib = import_module('matplotlib',
    876             __import__kwargs={'fromlist': ['pyplot', 'cm', 'collections']},
AttributeError: 'Circle' object has no attribute 'is_3D'
```

Comment: Simply typing `Circle((0,0),1)` in a notebook should show a circle. But yes, there are bugs.

Comment: I can reproduce the error using sympy 0.7. However you link to the documentation of sympy 1.1.1. Which version are you using?

Comment: The error can be reproduced in both sympy 0.7 and sympy 1.1.1.

Answer (score 3):

Those examples are from "pygletplot" module which basically doesn't work (certainly not under Python 3), and hasn't been tested or developed for years. What SymPy can plot:

- graphs y=f(x), with `plot`
- parametric curves, with `plot_parametric`
- implicit curves, with `plot_implicit`
- 3D graphs z=f(x, y), with `plot3d`
- parametric curves in 3D, with `plot3d_parametric_line`
- parametric surface, with `plot3d_parametric_surface`

Comment: So, explicitly,... there is no function to plot "Geometric Primitives" from SymPy? That is a pitty! :)